# lyft flyte errors on startup following docs?

Tags: flyte

Getting the follow running the example from the docs. Anyone have ideas why?

Looks like gprc. Maybe this is related? https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15933

```
docker run --network host -e FLYTE_PLATFORM_URL='127.0.0.1:30081' lyft/flytesnacks:v0.1.0 pyflyte -p flytesnacks -d development -c sandbox.config register workflows
Using configuration file at /app/sandbox.config
Flyte Admin URL 127.0.0.1:30081
Running task, workflow, and launch plan registration for flytesnacks, development, ['workflows'] with version 46045e6383611da1cb763d64d846508806fce1a4
Registering Task:                workflows.edges.edge_detection_canny
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/venv/bin/pyflyte", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flytekit/clis/sdk_in_container/register.py", line 86, in workflows
    register_all(project, domain, pkgs, test, version)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flytekit/clis/sdk_in_container/register.py", line 24, in register_all
    o.register(project, domain, name, version)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flytekit/common/exceptions/scopes.py", line 158, in system_entry_point
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flytekit/common/tasks/task.py", line 141, in register
    _engine_loader.get_engine().get_task(self).register(id_to_register)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flytekit/engines/flyte/engine.py", line 234, in register
    self.sdk_task
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flytekit/clients/friendly.py", line 50, in create_task
    spec=task_spec.to_flyte_idl()
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flytekit/clients/raw.py", line 12, in handler
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flytekit/clients/raw.py", line 77, in create_task
    return self._stub.CreateTask(task_create_request)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 604, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 506, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1578482148.715995870","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3876,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1578482148.715993301","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":395,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `FLYTE_PLATFORM_URL='127.0.0.1:30081'`.Minikube runs in VM on OSX. 
When you run `docker run --network host`, the docker daemon shares the networking namespace with this host - https://docs.docker.com/network/host/
Thus if you have the docker daemon and Kubernetes running on the same host (not a VM), you should be able to refer to services (nodeport) or ingress on Kubernetes using 127.0.0.1. 
But, since minikube runs in a VM on osx, you will need to use `minikube ip` to find the ip address of the minikube machine and then set

FLYTE_PLATFORM_URL=':30081'